# Comparing times in SQL

Tags: sql

I've been coding, and I stumbled upon an issue; I need to delete all rows where the current time is bigger than the time in the row + 15 minutes.

For example, I'm storing the time '13:17:05' in a row. (17 is the minutes)
And let's say the current time is '13:34:28'.
I need to add 15 minutes to the time in the row (so instead of 13:17:05 it'll be 13:32:05), and then if the current time is smaller than the new time in the row, I want to delete the row.

How can I do that?

Thanks,
Tom.

Comment: [DateAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) for TSQL

Comment: I doubt searches like "add times in SQL" and "compare times in SQL" return no results...

Answer (score 0):

Try this[for oracle, timeval has to be datetime column as point having just time column]:

```
Delete from table where sysdate > timeVal +15/1440;
```

It will delete all rows have sysdategreater than 15 minutes from timeVal .